# Remove character from a string if previous character is a specified character

Tags: c++, replace

If I have a string like this :

> asdasda=1lsdn=sdf=3dfsdf=-sadf= adfgh=1fbfg=fgfg

what is the fastest way to remove a character if 1) it comes after an `=` and 2) that character is a non alphabet.

In this case the o/p of the function will be :

> asdasda=lsdn=sdf=dfsdf=sadf=adfgh=fbfg=fgfg

I am coding in c++.

This is what I have so far

> ```
> std::string b = "asdasda=1lsdn=sdf=3dfsdf=-sadf= adfgh=1fbfg=fgfg";
> int a= 1;
> while(a != 0){ 
>     a = b.find('=', a);
>     a++;
>     if(!isalpha(b[a])){
>         b.erase(a,1);
>     }   
> }   
> std::cout << b << std::endl;
> ```

Comment: This works most of the time.But, a corner case would be "a"(index) can be last index of the string. a++  will go passed the size of the array and isalpha(a[a]) is accessing array outside it's bounds. Just noticed, you have string and int have same variable names.

Comment: Looks like you edited the variable names. But, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a c++ developer but how much i know c++ ,i think best solution for your problem is.

```
std::string s("asdasda=1lsdn=sdf=3dfsdf=-sadf=adfgh=1fbfg=fgfg");
std::string::size_type k = 0;
/*erase character after =*/ 
while((k=s.find('=',k))!=s.npos) {
   s.erase(k+1, 1);
}

/*erase numeric*/
for(i=0;i<=9;i++) {
 std::string::size_type n = 0;
 while((n=s.find(i,n))!=s.npos) {
   s.erase(n, 1);
}
```

}

There in code may be syntax error , Please check this code before use.

thanks

Comment: +1 for not being a C++ developer and then coming up with a solution using STL. There are problems in code but gave +1 for a good attempt.

Comment: thank  you very much, when you got any solution please let me know , it will helpful for me..

Comment: @Jagannath Where is any STL in his solution?

Comment: @JamesKanze, std::string I took it as STL. Is that not part of STL ?

Comment: @Jagannath It is and it isn't.  The original STL did *not* contain a string class.  The string class which had been proposed was augmented with some STL features, however (like STL iterators).  Had the code used these, I wouldn't have said anything, but one of the basic tenets of the STL is for operations be implemented by free function templates, using iterators, and not be members.  A solution based on functions in `<algorithm>` and string members like `begin()`, `end()` and `push_back()` could be considered using the STL.  The proposed solution, no.

Answer (score 1):

Most important is to perform the loop and copy each character only once.

So don't try to remove each character one by one (and shift all the characters after it).

Keep 2 pointers into your string:

- one pointing to the last valid/stored character
- one pointing to the next character that you will check

Initialize both pointing to the first character.

Check the character at the second pointer:

- if it's a normal character, not to be removed, put it at the place of the first pointer (if the pointers are still not identical) and increase the first and second pointer.
- if it's a character to be removed, just increase the second pointer

At the end, be sure to write a terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously attempt to code.. but anyhow you can use this as a reference to start.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void remove_non_alpha(char *s)
{ 
    int i=0, j=0;

    while(s[i]) {
        if (isalpha(s[i])) {
            s[j++] = s[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    s[j] = '\0';

    return;
}

void remove_after(char *s, char c)
{
    int i=0, j=0;

    while(s[i]) {
        if (s[i] == c) {
            s[j++] = s[i++];
            if (s[i] == '\0') break;
        } else { 
            s[j++] = s[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    s[j] = '\0';

    return;
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "asdasda=1lsdn=sdf=3dfsdf=-sadf= adfgh=1fbfg=fgfg";
    char b[] = "asdasda=1lsdn=sdf=3dfsdf=-sadf= adfgh=1fbfg=fgfg";

    printf("sample string: %s \n", a);
    remove_after(a, '=');
    printf("final string : %s \n", a);

    printf("sample string: %s \n", b);
    remove_non_alpha(b);
    printf("final string : %s \n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
$ gcc remove.c 
$ ./a.out 
sample string: asdasda=1lsdn=sdf=3dfsdf=-sadf= adfgh=1fbfg=fgfg 
final string : asdasda=lsdn=df=dfsdf=sadf=adfgh=fbfg=gfg 
sample string: asdasda=1lsdn=sdf=3dfsdf=-sadf= adfgh=1fbfg=fgfg 
final string : asdasdalsdnsdfdfsdfsadfadfghfbfgfgfg 
$
```

I have given you `C` program. Now, attempt a `C++` program using `STL`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the functions in algorithm, returning the
results:

```
std::string
eraseAfterEq( std::string const& original )
{
    std::string results;
    std::string::const_iterator current = original.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator next = std::find( current, original.end(), '=' );
    while ( next != original.end() ) {
        ++ next;
        results.append( current, next );
        current = std::find_if( next, original.end(), IsAlpha() );
        next = std::find( current, original.end(), '=' );
    }
    results.append( current, next );
    return results;
}
```

or if you want to modify the string in place:

```
void
eraseAfterEq( std::string& original )
{
    std::string::iterator current = std::find( original.begin(), original.end(), '=' );
    while ( current != original.end() ) {
        ++ current;
        std::string::iterator next = std::find_if( current, original.end(), IsAlpha() );
        current = std::find( original.erase( current, next ), original.end(), '=' );
    }
}
```

In both cases, `IsAlpha` is a functional object which should be in your
toolbox:

```
template <std::ctype_base::mask m>
class Is : public std::unary_function<char, bool>
{
    std::locale myLocale;    //  To ensure lifetime of facet...
    std::ctype<char> const* myCType;
public:
    Is( std::locale const& locale = std::locale() )
        : myLocale( locale )
        , myCType( &std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >( myLocale ) )
    {
    }
    bool operator()( char toTest ) const
    {
        return myCType->is( m, toTest );
    }
};

typedef Is<std::ctype_base::alpha> IsAlpha;
//  ...
```

I'd generally go with the functional version.  If it's not fast enough,
you can experiment with the other.  It might be faster, since it will
never have to allocate new memory.  (Or it might be slower, since it
copies a lot more.  For your sample string, the copying will
probably be cheaper than an allocation, but this will depend on the
actual data, the compiler, and the system you're working on.)

You can also experiment with simpler versions of `IsAlpha`, if you don't
need locale support, or if you can be sure of the lifetime of the
`locale` you are using. The C version (in `<ctype.h>`) of `isalpha` is
often faster as well (just don't forget that you can't pass it a `char`
directly—you have to `static_cast` it to `unsigned char` first).
Alternatively, you can experiment using `std::ctype::scan_is` rather
than the `std::find_if`; it will take some hacking to use it, however,
since it only supports `char const*`: if I went this route, I'd probably
use `char const*` as my iterators, with `&original[0]` and `&original[0]
+ original.size()` as `begin()` and `end()`.  (The `std::locale`
interface is particularly poorly designed.)

Without actually experimenting and measuring, I can't tell you which
solution would be fastest.  And even after experimenting and measuring,
I could only tell you which was fastest on my machine and in the exact
context in which I did my measurements.  It might not be the fastest on
your machine.  Just use whichever of the two simple versions is most
appropriate, and don't worry about the performance until you need to.